# Sklearn: Cloning custom transform replaces values in __init__ dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn, copy, cloning

Let us say we have a custom transform `A` that has some arguments. When the `A` is instantiated, these arguments are set in the init.

When we clone `A` (as happens in `cross_val_score`, for example), the arguments get copied successfully.

However, if the arguments are sent to a structure such as a dictionary, the clone replaces them with None.

In cases where None does not cause errors, this creates a silent error, as the cloned version of `A` will run, producing different results from its original version (which is how I ran into this problem in the first place).

Fully replicable example follows (`sklearn version '0.20.3'`).

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.base import clone


class MyTransformA(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, n_cols_to_keep):
        self.cols_to_keep_dict = {'n_cols': n_cols_to_keep}  

    def fit(self, X, *_):
        return self 

    def transform(self, X, *_):
        return X


class MyTransformB(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, n_cols_to_keep):
        self.n_cols_to_keep = n_cols_to_keep  # <--- this time we save the input immediately 
        self.cols_to_keep_dict = {'n_cols': self.n_cols_to_keep}  

    def fit(self, X, *_):
        return self 

    def transform(self, X, *_):
        return X

my_transform_a = MyTransformA(n_cols_to_keep=5)
my_transform_a_clone = clone(my_transform_a)

my_transform_b = MyTransformB(n_cols_to_keep=5)
my_transform_b_clone = clone(my_transform_b)

print('Using MyTransformA:')
print('  my_transform_a.cols_to_keep_dict:        %s' % str(my_transform_a.cols_to_keep_dict))
print('  my_transform_a_clone.cols_to_keep_dict:  %s  <------ ?' % str(my_transform_a_clone.cols_to_keep_dict))

print('\nUsing MyTransformB:')
print('  my_transform_b.cols_to_keep_dict:        %s' % str(my_transform_b.cols_to_keep_dict))
print('  my_transform_b_clone.cols_to_keep_dict): %s' % str(my_transform_b_clone.cols_to_keep_dict))
```

Expected Results

```
Using MyTransformA:
  my_transform_a.cols_to_keep_dict:        ('n_cols', 5)
  my_transform_a_clone.cols_to_keep_dict:  ('n_cols', 5)  <------ Does not happen

Using MyTransformB:
  my_transform_b.cols_to_keep_dict:        {'n_cols': 5}
  my_transform_b_clone.cols_to_keep_dict): {'n_cols': 5}
```

Actual Results

```
Using MyTransformA:
  my_transform_a.cols_to_keep_dict:        ('n_cols', 5)
  my_transform_a_clone.cols_to_keep_dict:  ('n_cols', None)  <------ ?

Using MyTransformB:
  my_transform_b.cols_to_keep_dict:        {'n_cols': 5}
  my_transform_b_clone.cols_to_keep_dict): {'n_cols': 5}
```